# Как правильно написать функцию которая из строки возвращает подстроку между запятыми

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки

Есть задача. Дана строка, вывести на экран ту ее часть, которая находится между первой и второй запятой (последующие запятые игнорировать), подстроку записать с заглавной буквы.Если второй запятой нет, вывести весь текст после первой запятой. К примеру, строка: "Proin tincidunt, ipsum non auctor aliquet, lorem sapien viverra nunc, eu finibus eros enim in quam.". Вывести на экран: "Ipsum non auctor aliquet". Я пытался сделать через класс. Поиск второй запятой обдумываю через цикл, но пока ищу альтернативу, так что выводит толко текст после первой запятой. Вот что получилось:

```
public class GetSubString {
    private String startString;
    private char separator;

    //Конструктор
    public GetSubString(String str, char separ){
      startString = str;
      separator = separ;
    }

    public String getBetweenComma(){
        if (startString.length() < 1){
            return "Строка закортка!";
        }
        int firstSepar = startString.indexOf(separator);
        return startString.substring(firstSepar+2);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String str1 = "Ut libero diam, iaculis id lectus sed, gravida scelerisque metus.";


        GetSubString subString = new GetSubString(str1,',');
        System.out.println(subString.getBetweenComma());
    }

}
```

Comment: Да просто сделай string.split по символу запятой и из полученного массива  возьми второй (который с индексом 1) элемент.

Comment: @Akina Я рассматривал этот вариант, но думал написать нечто свое и разобрать его работу

Comment: Еще можно регулярные выражения использовать, если скучно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Скучно, но пока не на столько))

Comment: @ЮрийГалай тогда берите split =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, другого варианта написать самому нет?(

Comment: @почему же, есть и Вы его начали изобретать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать метод `indexOf` для поиска второй запятой?

Например,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "Proin tincidunt, ipsum non auctor aliquet, " +
                   "lorem sapien viverra nunc, eu finibus eros enim in quam.";

        int firstComma = s.indexOf( ',' ) + 1;  
        int secondComma  = s.indexOf( ',', firstComma );

        if ( secondComma == -1 ) secondComma = s.length();

        System.out.println( firstComma + " : " + secondComma );

        System.out.println( s.substring( firstComma, secondComma ) );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
16 : 41
 ipsum non auctor aliquet
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, сейчас попробую реализовать. Будет ли наглостью спросить для личного образования: "Есть ли еще какие-нибудь идеи?"?)

Comment: @ЮрийГалай Я поверхностно знаю Java, а потому сходу что-то другое, помимо того, что указано в комментариях, предложить не могу.:)